# how to automate pressing a button on a website

Tags: javascript

I need to write a JavaScript program that clicks buttons on a site for few times. I tried to wrote it, but it click only one time and then stops.

```js
let button = document.querySelector("path to the button");
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    button.click();
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1hm3t6zn/

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem is that the "path to the button" is wrong. When you use `querySelector` you need to specify a valid css selector.

Checkout my example below

```js
function doJobs(){
  let button = document.querySelector("#btn");
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      button.click();
  }
}

function sayHi(){
  alert("hi")
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="sayHi()">
 click me
</button>

<button onclick="doJobs()">
 doJobs
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a getElementById and give an id at your button like this

```
<button id="nameyouwant" />
```

I guess you gave a wrong name.